# Getting mapper_parsing_exception on creating a deleted elastic index again

Tags: elasticsearch, reindex

I have deleted an existing elastic index as part of reindexing, created a temp index and moved all the documents to the temp index before deleting this index. Now I'm getting this error when I'm trying to create the deleted index again.

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "unknown parameter [normalizer] on mapper [Type] of type [text]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [universal_profile]: unknown parameter [normalizer] on mapper [Type] of type [text]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "unknown parameter [normalizer] on mapper [Type] of type [text]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

What is the issue and how can I create that index again. any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I'm not sure why this is happening. I'm not able to create even an empty index with the existing index name.

Comment: Maybe add the command you're sending to create the new index? The issue is pretty clear that you are trying to specify a normalizer on a text field, normalizers are only available to keyword fields

Comment: @Val I'm just using a simple index create command. Not adding the normalizer.                                                                            
                                                                                                   PUT /universal_profiles_private
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 3,  
      "number_of_replicas": 2 
    }
  }
}

Comment: The above is the error you get when running that command ?

Comment: Yes. I have deleted universal_profiles_private index after reindex and I'm getting this error on creating this index again. Is there any issue with aliases or index patterns.

Comment: Do you have an index pattern that would be triggered for `universal_profiles_private`? That coud be the issue

Comment: "index_patterns": [
    "*universal_profiles_private*"
  ].  universal_profiles_private is the index pattern. Wont index pattren be deleted when we delete the index from kibana?

Comment: No index patterns have an independent lifecycle, deleting the index doesn't delete the index pattern, you need to delete it as well.

Comment: I have "universal_profiles*" pattern, I think I'm not able to create universal_profiles_private index because of universal_profiles* pattern and we have other indices in the cluster starts with universal_profiles* name. Can i delete this index pattern in this case and add the same again?

Comment: It depends on what it contains, there's not enough information in your question to make the call.